# permutation and combination of n numbers in array output of permutation and combination should be in two digits

Tags: javascript, laravel, combinations, permutation

I tried this code for combination of my input but I'm getting the output results of same length as I entered in my input field but I want only two digit output

```
let str = $('#num').val();
            let first = $('#first').val();
            let second = $('#second').val();
            let permutation = (str, result) => {
                if (str.length == 0) {
                    x = result;
                    y = Object.values(x);
                     console.log(result);
                   

                }
                for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    let rest = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1)

                    permutation(rest, result + str[i])
                }
            }
            permutation(str, '')
            var x = result;
```

for example
input:123
output that i want

12
13
21
23
31
32